# Set the length of a model field to a length of 5

Tags: python, django

I am using Django and I want to set one of my fields in my database to only allow numbers that are 5 integers long. I found max_length, is there a length?

Here is my code

```
zip_code = models.IntegerField(max_length=5)
```

Is there a way to

```
zip_code = models.IntegerField(length=5)
```

Force user to enter 5 numbers.

Comment: I would use a char field and then validate that all chars are numbers

Comment: To answer the actual question though, saying that a number can have a maximum of 5 digits is to say that its max value is 99999, so you could use [`MaxValueValidator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/validators/#maxvaluevalidator).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to use `max_length` with an `IntegerField`.

If you are storing zip codes, it would be better to use a `CharField`, so that you can store zip codes that begin with zero.

CharFields do not have a `min_length` option, but Django does have a `MinLengthValidator`. However, it would be simpler to use a [`RegexValidator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/validators/#regexvalidator), then you can use a regex to allow only digits, and check that the input is exactly 5 digits long.

```
zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=5, validators=[RegexValidator(r'^[0-9]{5}$')])
```

Another option would be to use the `USZipCodeField` from [django-localflavor](http://django-localflavor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/localflavor/us/).